# Is it possible to utilize CodedUI without access to the code base

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have been asked to write an automated test suite. The project manager has asked me to use Visual studio CodedUI, but this has raised issues with the development team who don't want me to have access to the source code, which I understand.

I normally use Selenium Webdriver for automation.

If I was to write tests in CodedUI would I need access to the source code and would my tests interfere with the source code i.e. code could go out of sync and add additional dependencies

or I should I be able kept my tests completely independent like I can with Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need access to the source code, just the application and visual studio.

I don't agree with the position on blocking access to the source code.

Not being able to build and test against the latest code will cause testing to lag far behind development.  Development and testing should really happen at the same time.

Test early and often:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee330950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx